# Global variable returning nil value when used in diffrent view controller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have 4 global variables (String arrays) which i am appending in one view controller(say firstViewController). After appending values when i try to access them in another view controller a nil value is being passed

First ViewController

```
print("\(json)")
            if let stockInfo = json?[0] {

                if let value = stockInfo["l"] as? String {
                    print("Teja\(value)")
                    stockCurrentValue.append(value)
                    print("Teja\(stockCurrentValue)")

                }

                if let cp = stockInfo["cp"] as? String{
                    print("Teja\(cp)")
                    stockCp.append(cp)
                    print("Tea\(stockCp)")
                }

                if  let c = stockInfo["c"] as? String{
                    print("Teja\(c)")
                    stockC.append(c)

                }
                if let pcls_fix = stockInfo["pcls_fix"] as? String{

                    print("Teja\(pcls_fix)")
                    stockPrevValue.append(pcls_fix)

                }


            }
```

The variables stockCurrentValue,stockC, stockCP, stockPrevValue are the four global variables i declared.

But when i try to access them in a new viewController

SecondViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print(selectedStockNames.count)
    return selectedStockNames.count


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myStocks") as! StockCell

        cell.stockNameCell.text = selectedStockNames[indexPath.row]


    print("Teja123\(stockCurrentValue)")

    stockValueFromGF = selectedStockValues[indexPath.row]

    print("Teja123\(stockCp)")

    return cell
}
```

So when i print StockCp value in firstViewContoller i get the value but when i try to print the same variable in seconViewController i get "[]" (nil value)

Comment: how do you determine the `stockCurrentValue` in `SecondViewController`? Are you sure it is taken from the `FirstViewController`? Even though those properties of `FirstViewController` is publicly accessible, you need to explicitly call for it some point in time in your `SecondViewController` like `stockCurrentValue = firstVC.stockCurrentValue` where firstVC is an instance of `FirstViewController` otherwise `FirstViewController.shared.stockCurrentValue` if it is a singleton

Comment: I have all the variables declared in a seperate swift file. How can i create an instance firstVc, can youhelp me with that please.

Comment: I am quite sure you do not create an instance of a `UIViewController` to just retrieve a few values from its subclass. If you have used a `UIViewController` subclass you should have at some point already created it, probably via storyboard if you did not realise you did so. To reference that instance of `FirstViewController` you should consider retrieving it from the ViewController presenting it(rootViewController if there isn't any) or it might just be the one that is presenting `SecondViewController`. In that case you can pass the values in right before the presentation.

Comment: Alternatively you need to show me how you populate `SecondViewController` properties such as `selectedStockValues` and `stockCurrentValue` for me to help you identify your mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use protocol and define it in the View Controller from where you want to set the values.

Use the method inside the function where the values of the global variables change.

Call the function and set the delegate in the view controller where you want to access the variables.